# no puedo subir los cambios de otra rama

Tags: git

[image: postulaciones@solutoria.help]

estoy subiendo los cambios de mi proyecto a la rama parte3 donde se han ejecutado los cambios, me da el siguiente error que se ve en la imagen, y que esta empujando o interviniendo la siguiente url'https://github.com/jpaiton2334/proyecto-titulo-part-1 yo lo quiero subir a "https://github.com/jpaiton2334/proyecto-titulo"

Comment: El problema está en que hay revisiones que están en la rama `parte3` de github que no están en tu rama, por eso git no deja que coloques tu rama en el remoto. El flujo normal es que hagas un pull de la rama para traer esos cambios a tu rama.

Comment: ejecuta `git log --oneline --graph parte3 origin/parte3` para que lo veas "graficamente". :-D

Comment: Ya hiciste `git pull`?

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, mañana lo probaré

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se realiza rebase o se sobreescribe cambios a la rama actual, obtenemos ese error, para subir sus cambios se necesita forzarlo con -f

en su caso seria

```
  git push -f origin parte3
```

Answer (score 1):

git push -f origin parte3
Pero ten en cuenta que si en tu rama "parte3" tienes avances distintos a los de la rama principal, los perderás.

(-f significa --force) con ello haces un envío forzado, lo necesitas para sobrescribir información, también te puede suceder al hacer push a github.

Te dejo la fuente: https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push